# Spock method mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I've got method that is responsible for changing a flag to disabled of passed object to it. The purpose is to test if that method changed that flag. I'm using spock framework for it. Method is invoked on interface and is implemented by JPA module.I can't find any way to mock this method

```
Interface MyService {
    public void update();
}

interface MyRepositoryService {
    //implemented by JPA module
    public void update(MyObject myObject);
}

class MyObject {
    //..
    private boolean disable;
    //..
}
```

Module under specification:

```
class MyServiceImplementation implements MyService {
   private MyRepositoryService myRepositoryService;

   //method to be mocked
   void update(MyObject myObject){
      //...
      myRepository.update(myObject)
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm loosing smth, but just declare a **Mock** - if you're going to test interactions between objects - or a **Stub** if you're going to test just method behaviour.

Instance your tested object calling the constructor manually passing it the mocked object and code your test.

using Groovy syntax for a quick example:

```
class MyServiceImplementationUnitTest extends Specification {

  def Repository repository = Mock(Repository)

  @Subject MyService service = new MyService(
      ...
      repository // the mock      
  )

  // an example guidelines for a possible test
  def "this is a test"() {
    given: "an input object"
      def inputObject = SMTH
    when: "we call update method with that object"
      service.update(inputObject)
    then: "repository's update method is called once with expected parameter"
      1 * repository.update(inputObject)
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to check not if the method was called but changes made on object passed to that update method. And as far as I know I need to mock that method to do so.

Comment: @Luca sorry but... nop. The unit test for the code you've post is the code above. Your class has a method, when you call that method, delegates into an internal object calling a method with the given parameter. It is possible you're looking for the unit test of the class `Repository` (the delegate), but from the outside I do not know what is `repository.update(obj)` doing to the obj. If that behaviour changes, the code of MyService will still be ok :)
Checking if the obj has changed would make this a "2-clases-integration-test"

Comment: You are right that what I want to achieve comes down to integration test